# python execute subprocess without waiting for subprocess to terminate

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd, subprocess

Is it possible to start subprocess without waiting for it to terminate?
I have a Windows program that I need to execute in python script and I want to leave it run on background without waiting for the subprocess to quit since the program is expecting input to terminate itself (press q to quit).

I have tried many ways but none of them worked.

What I basically want to achieve is the following:

```
args = [os.path.join(path, 'myProgram.exe'), '/run']

p = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

and do some other stuff here with the myProgram.exe still running.

The myProgram.exe can also be installed as service. When I tried this approach by

```
subprocess.call('net start myService', shell=True)
```

the service always fails to start. It fails with system error code 1067 which means the process terminated unexpectedly.

NOTE: I'm using python 2.7

Thanks for the advices.

Edit:
I have found a workaround which I don't understand...
As workaround I've created a myProgram.bat file which starts myProgram.exe.
BUT there's a catch, if I do only

> start myProgram.exe

it behaves exactly the same as when calling subprocess - it terminates. However if I do

> > timeout 0 -- @means wait 0 seconds
> >
> > start myProgram.exe

the program starts normally.

Comment: I am not clear about why the first approach won't work? That would exactly be my suggestion...

Comment: That's the problem, me either. Both of the approaches should work. I don't just know why the program is terminated. Plus it ends with return code 1, which means there was some error but I can't reach the error any way. It's not in the program's log nor in strerr.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call a program from python without waiting for it to return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602052/how-to-call-a-program-from-python-without-waiting-for-it-to-return)

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
args = ['start', os.path.join(path, 'myProgram.exe'), '/run']
```

see `start /?` for help ( or http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm)

Comment: Tried:
args = ['start', os.path.join(path, 'myProgram.exe'), '/run']
p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)
But the window opens and immediatelly closes.

Comment: what happends if your enter `myProgram.exe /run` in command line?
start just opens a new command line and then returns to python...

Answer (score 0):

If the program expects a `q` to quit, maybe send it one?

```
args = [os.path.join(path, 'myProgram.exe'), '/run']
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
...
p.stdin.write("q\n")
```

Comment: When I do:
> p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
the subprocess.Popen executes the program and it terminates immediately.
I don't want to quit that program.